# @ServerEndpoint not working on Spring boot v2.3.7

Tags: spring-boot, java-websocket

Server is running but i cant use chatendpoint.java class. So spring not using /user path. And i cant connect ws://localhost:8080/user . When i try it i am getting error

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/user")
public class ChatEndpoint {
    private Session session;
    private static final Set<ChatEndpoint> chatEndpoints = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();
    private static HashMap<String, String> users = new HashMap<>();

    @OnOpen
    public void OnOpen (Session session) {
        System.out.println(" asdasd");
        System.out.println(session.toString()+" asdasd");
    }
      @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session, Message message) throws 
    IOException, EncodeException {
       System.out.println("send message");

    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig  {

    @Bean
    public ServerEndpointExporter endpointExporter(){
        return new ServerEndpointExporter();
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class WebsocketdemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebsocketdemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I am using spring-boot-starter-websocket 2.3.7.RELEASE and spring-websocket 5.2.12.RELEASE

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-messaging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-websocket -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.12.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: can someone help ?

Answer (score 2):

I found solution. Delete @EnableWebSocket because i am using @serverendpoint annotation that is providing spesific websocket handle. Second i have

```
    @OnMessage
public void onMessage(Session session, Message message) throws IOException, EncodeException {
    System.out.println("send message");
   
}
```

Message message parametres causing compile error i changed it with String message paramet. And add @component to Chatendpoint class. Because spring and tomcat can understand it that is a component.

```
       @Component
    @ServerEndpoint(value = "/user")
    public class ChatEndpoint {

    @OnOpen
    public void OnOpen (Session session) {
        
    }
   
       @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session, String message) throws IOException, EncodeException {
        System.out.println("send message");
       
    }
}
```